# Capturing small details in textures without making a huge map

Tags: textures

Ex. Nuts and bolts on a cabinet. Said items are tiny relative to the cabinet, and on a texture map looks like an indistinguishable dot. Is it worth it to separate these tiny details into a mesh of their own? Obvious cons are increasing poly count and draw calls, disregarding how much of an increase that would be. Is there a generally accepted way of going about this?

Comment: Depends entirely on your polygon budget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it sounds like you're using a human sized perspective, you can either increase your texture or your polygon budget. Usually, you would bake fine geometry into something like a normal map, but if it's that small then it probably isn't worth it unless that's a vital part of gameplay. If it is, then go ahead and use a model for it. Just be careful that you aren't blowing all your resources on things the player isn't going to look twice at.

A game with multiple size perspectives (if the player can grow or shrink to that size) could use variable level of detail - to increase the detail of now large objects - and depth of field - to hide distant objects consuming unnecessary draw cycles - for these things, but that implies a lot more engineering than it's worth if they aren't going to be spending much time there.

Answer (score 0):

If you find that geometry is too heavy weight, bump mapping can be a great way of getting the appearance of geometric detail without paying the geometry costs.

Answer (score 0):

Using decals and even meshes of highly varying scale for additional detail is completely fine and has been done for quite some time already (I'd say at least 20 years or so, since the dawn of somewhat realistic 3D).

Yes, it's definitely worth it. And no, there's nothing wrong about making something as long as it looks right and meets all performance requirements.

For example, The Last of Us still did things like that: http://goingsony.com/system/file_uploads/uploads/000/002/792/original/60fps3.jpg - if you look closely, it can be seen that level of texture detail isn't exactly matching for all foliage.

Though of course, before you make detail like that, you should probably make sure that someone will actually be able to see that detail. Not much point investing in polishing for rarely visited or distant areas.

P.S.

> into a mesh of their own

For meshes that support multiple materials, that should not be necessary. The detail can be added into the same mesh. Unless you need many meshes of the same kind together, in which case it might be easier to just export all variations separately, if you use a visual editor of any kind.